# How to set Content-ID header to the correct request in SAP Hybrid Application Toolkit?

Tags: http-headers, odata, sapui5, hybrid-mobile-app, offlineapps

I am trying to generate a batch request for the creation of two entities: a Parent entity and a Child entity belonging to that parent. For the linkage between them I want to use OData Content-ID header. I generate the request by this:

```
    this.model.create("/ParentSet", {
            Id: "000777000",
            Store: "16"
        }, {
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert("create error" + JSON.stringify(errormessage));
            },
            headers: {
                "content-ID": 1
            }
        });

        this.model.create("/$1/ToChild", {

            Id: "131313",
            Area: ""

        }, {
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert("create error" + JSON.stringify(errormessage));
            }

        });
```

When executed from the web sapui5 application the code results in the creation of the correct request payload:

```
--batch_a8d1-2414-ee3e
content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_0f62-99e1-b9a4

--changeset_0f62-99e1-b9a4
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary

POST ParentSet HTTP/1.1
content-ID: 1
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-GB
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: UrrKfxCwzgpBlY8GVgtdWg==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 31

{"Id":"000777000","Store":"16"}
--changeset_0f62-99e1-b9a4
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary

POST $1/ToChild HTTP/1.1
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-GB
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: UrrKfxCwzgpBlY8GVgtdWg==
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 48

{"Id":"131313","Area":""}
--changeset_0f62-99e1-b9a4--

--batch_a8d1-2414-ee3e
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary

GET ParentSet/$count HTTP/1.1
sap-cancel-on-close: true
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: text/plain, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-GB
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: UrrKfxCwzgpBlY8GVgtdWg==


--batch_a8d1-2414-ee3e
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary

GET ParentSet?$skip=0&$top=100 HTTP/1.1
sap-cancel-on-close: true
sap-contextid-accept: header
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-GB
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
x-csrf-token: UrrKfxCwzgpBlY8GVgtdWg==


--batch_a8d1-2414-ee3e--
```

However, when executed from the Cordova based SAP HAT application, the content-id header is placed to the change set instead to the Parent entity like that:

```
--batch_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_1
content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_2

--changeset_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_2
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-id: 1

POST ParentSet HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json;q=1, application/atom+xml;q=0.5
accept-language: en-US
sap-contextid-accept: header

{"Id":"000777000","Store":"16"}
--changeset_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_2
content-type: application/http
content-transfer-encoding: binary

POST $1/ToChild HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json;q=1, application/atom+xml;q=0.5
accept-language: en-US
sap-contextid-accept: header

{"Id":"131313","Area":""}
--changeset_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_2--

--batch_709b8b9352ac4342a0efb1e012d_1--
```

Does anyone have any suggestion of how this problem can be solved so that the content-id header gets attatched correctly to the Parent entity and not to the change set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the offline configuration in SAP CP Mobile Services. Under **Mobile Application > Native/Hybrid > Info > Assigned Features > Offline > Configuration** you need to click on the edit button. In the popup-menu
the Content ID Header Location had to be set to "Operation" instead if "Mime".

[screenshot of the configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRylQ.png)

[screenshot of the configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxD5m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(your header data here);    
this.getView().setModel(oModel,"HeaderDataModel");
// and then you can use header data anywhere in the view using "HeaderDataModel"

<button enabled ="{HeaderDataModel>/HeaderAttr2}">
```

its from here:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/31885/ui5-path-to-parent-property.html